# Randomly bouncing balls with constant tails in a spherical constraint

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, asymptote, fun

How easy is the following animation made with TikZ, PSTricks, and Asymptote?

[image]

Use the following as a starting template to save your time.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
.
\end{document}
```

Comment: A challenging problem that I'll look into after the thesis is out of the way. In the meantime, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection might help.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Not perfect, not optimal, not commented, not quick to compile, and not portable. Requires `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=.125cm]{standalone}
\directlua{%

Vector = {}
Vector.__index = Vector

function Vector.new(x, y)
  local obj = {x=x, y=y}
  setmetatable(obj, Vector)
  return obj
end

function Vector.fromPolar(a, r)
  return Vector.new(math.cos(math.rad(a))*r, math.sin(math.rad(a))*r)
end

function Vector:copy()
  return Vector.new(self.x, self.y)
end

function Vector.__add(p, q)
  return Vector.new(p.x+q.x, p.y+q.y)
end

function Vector.__sub(p, q)
  return Vector.new(p.x-q.x, p.y-q.y)
end

function Vector.__mul(p, q)
  if getmetatable(p) == Vector then
    if getmetatable(q) == Vector then
      return p.x*q.x + p.y*q.y
    else
      return Vector.new(p.x*q, p.y*q)
    end
  else
    return Vector.new(p*q.x, p*q.y)
  end
end

function Vector.__div(p, q)
  return Vector.new(p.x/q, p.y/q)
end

function Vector.__unm(p)
  return Vector.new(-p.x, -p.y)
end

function Vector:length()
  return math.sqrt(self.x^2 +  self.y^2)
end

function Vector:angle()
  return math.atan2(self.y, self.x)
end

function Vector:normalised()
  local l
  l = self:length()
  if l > 0 then
    return self / l
  else
    return Vector.new(0,0)
  end
end

function Vector:tostring()
  return "(" .. self.x .. ", " .. self.y .. ")"
end



History = {}
History.__index = History

function History.new(l)
  local obj = {data={}, length=l, _i=1}
  setmetatable(obj, History)
  return obj
end

function History:update(v)
  self.data[self._i] = v
  self._i = self._i + 1
  if self._i > self.length then
    self._i = 1
  end
end

function History:get(i)
  local j
  j = self._i - i 
  if j < 1 then
    j = j + self.length
  end
  return self.data[j]
end

function History:tostring()
  local s, i
  s = self:get(1):tostring()
  for i = 2,self.length do
    s = s .. " -- " .. self:get(i):tostring()
  end 
  return s
end


Ball = {}
Ball.__index = Ball

function Ball.new(pos, dir, r, h, c)
  h = h or 1
  c = c or "black"
  local obj = {pos=pos, dir=dir, radius=r, history=History.new(h), color=c}
  setmetatable(obj, Ball)
  local i
  for i=1,h do
    obj.history:update(pos)
  end
  return obj
end

function Ball:move()
  self.history:update(self.pos)
  self.pos = self.pos + self.dir
end

function Ball:collide(b)
  local d = self.pos - b.pos
  return d:length() <= (self.radius + b.radius)
end

function Ball:tostring()
  return self.pos:tostring() .. " circle [radius=" .. self.radius .. "]"
end
Arena = {}
Arena.__index = Arena

function Arena.new(R, n, r, h, col, ncol)
  local obj = {radius=R, balls={}, nballs=n}
  setmetatable(obj, Arena)
  local i, j, c, ball, done
  for i = 1,n do
    done = false
    while not done do
      c = col[math.random(1, ncol)]
      ball = Ball.new(Vector.fromPolar(math.random(0,359), math.random()*(R-r)), 
        Vector.fromPolar(math.random(0,359), math.random()), r, h, c)
      done = true
      if i > 1 then
        for j = 1,i-1 do
          if ball:collide(obj.balls[j]) then
            done = false
            break
          end
        end
      end
    end
    obj.balls[i] = ball
  end
  return obj
end

function Arena:update(K)
  K = K or 1
  local i, j, k, b, d, n, v
  local v1, v2, vn1, vn2, vt1, vt2
  for k = 1,K do
    for i = 1,self.nballs do
      self.balls[i]:move()
      if self.balls[i].pos:length() >= (self.radius-self.balls[i].radius) then
        n = -self.balls[i].pos:normalised()
        d = self.balls[i].dir
        self.balls[i].dir = d - 2*(d*n)*n
        self.balls[i]:move()
      end
      for j = 1,self.nballs do
        if not (i == j) then
          if self.balls[i]:collide(self.balls[j]) then
            d = self.balls[i].pos - self.balls[j].pos
            v1 = self.balls[i].dir
            v2 = self.balls[j].dir
            n = d:normalised()
            vn1 = (v1*(-n))*(-n)
            vn2 = (v2*n)*n
            vt1 = vn1 - v1
            vt2 = vn2 - v2
            v1 = vt1 + vn2
            v2 = vt2 + vn1
            self.balls[i].dir = v1
            self.balls[j].dir = v2
            self.balls[i]:move()
            self.balls[j]:move()
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
}

\def\getlua#1{\directlua{tex.print("" .. #1)}}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main} 
\begin{document}
\directlua{%
A = Arena.new(75, 20, 5, 75, {"red", "yellow", "pink", "green", "orange", "purple", "blue"}, 7)
}

\foreach \j in {1,...,100}{

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt]

\draw [very thick] circle [radius=\getlua{A.radius}];

\foreach \i in {1,...,\getlua{A.nballs}}{
% 
\fill [opacity=0.5] \getlua{A.balls[\i]:tostring()};
%
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \draw [very thick, line join=round, line cap=round, \getlua{A.balls[\i].color}] 
    \getlua{A.balls[\i].history:tostring()};
\end{pgfonlayer}
}

\directlua{A:update(5)}

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can watch this for 10 hours nonstop. `:)`

Comment: @CodeMocker You mean you want the balls to move faster? So fast that you can't count the balls?

Comment: @CodeMocker actually there appears to be some problems with the code as sometimes balls get stuck together or to the edge of the circle.

Comment: @MarkWibrow - Yes, the collision code in Arena:update doesn't look like standard Physics, and doesn't generate very realistic collisions.  This may be the cause of the strange behaviour you observed.  e.g. the collision between red and yellow at the 6'oclock position in frame 78 does not conserve momentum.

Comment: @AndrewKepert possibly, but every frame of the `gif` corresponds to 5 iterations of the `update` method. Most of the problems (I believe) with collisions stem from the fact that the balls are updated in a loop, and both balls in a collision are moved without checking if this leads to further collisions (until the next `update`). Either way it should be straightforward for someone who is more familiar with the "standard Physics" to replace the code as the overloaded operators in `Vector` class mean the necessary equations can be specified easily.

Comment: I'm having problems for its compilation, I have the last version of TexMaker and I'm trying to compile it with the Lualatex option, is there an other option or package to active ?

Comment: @Thomas the short answer is "no". It should just compile with lualatex without errors, but will take a very very very long time.